# Making DataTable results more readable

Tags: c#

I have the method below, which generates backtesting results. However, it's highly unreadable. What could you possibly suggest to me in order to make it more readable?

```csharp
public DataTable GenerateResultTable(List<BacktestResult> data)
{
    var table = new DataTable();

    table.Columns.Add("Pair");
    table.Columns.Add("Buys");
    table.Columns.Add("Avg Profit %");
    table.Columns.Add("Cum Profit %");
    table.Columns.Add($"Tot Profit {_backtestOptions.StakeCurrency}");
    table.Columns.Add("Tot Profit %");
    table.Columns.Add("Avg Duration");
    table.Columns.Add("Wins");
    table.Columns.Add("Draws");
    table.Columns.Add("Losses");

    // the number of the pairs in the backtest results
    var maxOpenOrders = data.GroupBy(e => e.Pair).Count();
    
    // Split results for each pair
    var query = data.GroupBy(e => e.Pair).Select(e => new { Pair = e.Key, Count = e.Count(), Value = e });

    // in case there are no records to show
    // if there are no rows, it throws an exception..
    if (!query.Any())
    {
        table.Rows.Add("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
    }

    foreach (var result in query)
    {
        var _profitSum = result.Value.Sum(e => e.ProfitPercentage);
        var _profitTotal = _profitSum / maxOpenOrders;

        var key = result.Pair;
        var trades = result.Count;
        var profitMean = trades > 0 ? result.Value.Average(e => e.ProfitPercentage) : 0;
        var profitMeanPercentage = trades > 0 ? result.Value.Average(e => e.ProfitPercentage) * 100 : 0;
        var profitSum = _profitSum;
        var profitSumPercentage = _profitSum * 100;
        var profitTotalAbs = result.Value.Sum(e => e.ProfitAbs);
        var profitTotal = _profitTotal;
        var profitTotalPercentage = _profitTotal * 100;
        var avgDuration = trades > 0 ? Math.Round(result.Value.Average(e => e.TradeDuration)) : 0;
        var wins = result.Value.Count(e => e.ProfitAbs > 0);
        var draws = result.Value.Count(e => e.ProfitAbs == 0);
        var losses = result.Value.Count(e => e.ProfitAbs < 0);

        table.Rows.Add(key, trades, $"{profitMeanPercentage:f2}", $"{profitSumPercentage:f2}", $"{profitTotalAbs:f8}", $"{profitTotalPercentage:f2}",
            $"{TimeSpan.FromMinutes((double)avgDuration):h\\:mm\\:ss}", wins, draws, losses);
    }

    return table;
}

public class BacktestOptions
{
    public string StakeCurrency { get; set; }
    public List<string> Pairs { get; set; }
    public string StrategyName { get; set; }
    public decimal StakeAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal OpenFee { get; set; }
    public decimal CloseFee { get; set; }
}

public class BacktestResult
{
    public string Pair { get; set; }
    public decimal ProfitPercentage { get; set; }
    public decimal ProfitAbs { get; set; }
    public decimal OpenRate { get; set; }
    public decimal CloseRate { get; set; }
    public DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CloseDate { get; set; }
    public decimal OpenFee { get; set; }
    public decimal CloseFee { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal TradeDuration { get; set; }
    public SellType SellReason { get; set; }
}
```

appsettings.json

```csharp
{
  "BacktestConfiguration": {
    "StakeCurrency": "USDT",
    "Pairs": [ "TRXUSDT" ],
    "StrategyName": "RsiStrategy",
    "StakeAmount": 1000,
    "OpenFee": 0.001,
    "CloseFee": 0.001
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share with use the code of the `BacktestResult` class and the declaration of `_backtestOptions`

Comment: @PeterCsala, added them both to the question. `_backtestOptions` is basically BacktestOptions retrieved from `appsettings.json`.

Comment: Why do you generate a `DataTable`?

Comment: @BCdotWEB, https://github.com/minhhungit/ConsoleTableExt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my observations:

- `List<BacktestResult> data`: Please try to use more expressive names than `data`. It is way too general and it does not help the reader / maintainer of the code. (same apply to `table` and `query`)
- Populating columns: Your implementation has a lot of repetition in it: `tables.Columns.Add`.

  - One way to reduce that by using the `AddRange`:

```cs
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.AddRange(new []
{
    new DataColumn("Pair"), 
    new DataColumn("Buys"), 
    new DataColumn("Avg Profit %"), 
    new DataColumn("Cum Profit %"), 
    new DataColumn($"Tot Profit {_backtestOptions.StakeCurrency}"), 
    new DataColumn("Tot Profit %"), 
    new DataColumn("Avg Duration"), 
    new DataColumn("Wins"), 
    new DataColumn("Draws"), 
    new DataColumn("Losses"), 
});
```

We are almost there, here we have repeated the `new DataColumn`. With the following technique you can separate data and logic:

```cs
var columns = new[]
{
    "Pair", "Buys", "Avg Profit %", "Cum Profit %", $"Tot Profit {_backtestOptions.StakeCurrency}",
    "Tot Profit %", "Avg Duration", "Wins", "Draws", "Losses"
};

table.Columns.AddRange(columns.Select(name => new DataColumn(name)).ToArray());
```

- `data.GroupBy(e => e.Pair)`: This has been called twice, but unnecessarily.

  - Materialize it by calling the `ToList` or `ToArray` on it:
  - With this approach we could get rid of the `maxOpenOrders` variable.

```cs
var resultsGroupByPair = data.GroupBy(e => e.Pair).ToArray();
var query = resultsGroupByPair.Select(br => new { Pair = br.Key, Count = br.Count(), Value = br });
//...
var _profitTotal = _profitSum / resultsGroupByPair.Length;
```

- `query`: Same applies here, *Possible multiple enumeration*

  - Materialize it by calling the `ToList` or `ToArray` on it
- `if there are no rows, it throws an exception..`: This comment is not align with the code. Try to comment the **Whys** and **Why not**s, not the **what** and **how**. The latter two should be clear by the code itself, but the chosen strategy (and the excluded alternatives) might not be obvious from the code.
- `profitMean`, `profitSum`, `profitTotal`: They are unused. If they are not needed then delete them.
- `trades > 0 ?`: This condition has been repeated several times.

  - Introduce a local variable and refer to that one instead: `bool isTradesPositive`
- `result.Value.Average`, `result.Value.Sum`: Same as in the previous case. If you use the same expression multiple times then save its result into a variable.
- `wins`, `draws`, `losses`: Instead do 3 iterations you can do it with a simple one.

  - For example with `Aggregate`:

```cs
var (wins, losses, draws) = result.Value.Aggregate((0, 0, 0), (outcome, e) =>
{
    if (e.ProfitAbs > 0) outcome.Item1++;
    else if (e.ProfitAbs < 0) outcome.Item2++;
    else outcome.Item3++;
    return outcome;
});
```

or

```cs
var (wins, losses, draws) = result.Value.Aggregate((0, 0, 0), 
    ((int winCount, int loseCount, int drawCount) outcome, BacktestResult e) =>
    {
        if (e.ProfitAbs > 0) outcome.winCount++;
        else if (e.ProfitAbs < 0) outcome.loseCount++;
        else outcome.drawCount++;
        return outcome;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! The second example with win, losses, draws doesn't work, because of `((int winCount, int loseCount, int drawCount) outcome, BacktestResult e)`.

Comment: @nop Could you please elaborate what do you mean by *doesn't work*? Does not compile? Does throw exception? Returns with three 0? or else?

Comment: These are the exceptions https://pastebin.com/EXnVhAtL. https://i.imgur.com/XUno1Jy.png

Comment: @nop This is compilation error. Let me check.

Comment: @nop What C# and .NET version are you using?

Comment: I'm using .NET 5

Comment: @nop It does compile, check [this dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zGgLHa). So, there should be something else in your project which causes this error.

Comment: It's because of the specified types of the arguments. No idea why that is. I guess I will stick to the .Item1, 2, 3 way. Thanks again